# Два класса в одной директории по-разному видят JDBC Driver

Tags: java, jdbc

Есть два класса - тестовый и основной. Оба подключаются к одной и той же БД, имеют одинаковые переменные URL, логина и пароля. Расположены классы в одной папке, и оба ссылаются на JDBC Driver из соседней директории.

При этом "тестовый" класс подключается без проблем, а основной - кидает ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. Импорты одинаковые, сам драйвер я уже пару раз удалял и добавлял заново.  В чем проблема?

тестовый класс:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class DBTest {

private static final String USERNAME = "root";
private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
private static final String DATABASEURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //создаем соеднинение для базы данных
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASEURL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String thisName = "ASFDF", thisGenre="ASDASDAS";
        double thisPrice = 23;
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO GameShop(name,genre,price) VALUE " +
                "('"+thisName+"','"+thisGenre+"','"+thisPrice+"')");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

основной класс:

```
package app.model;

import app.entities.StandartGame;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.List;

public class SingletonModel {
    private static SingletonModel model;
    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "root";
    private static final String DATABASEURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";

    public static synchronized void addGames(StandartGame ... gamez) {
    try {
        //создаем соеднинение для базы данных
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASEURL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        String thisName, thisGenre;
        double thisPrice;

        for (StandartGame stg : gamez) {
            thisName = stg.getName();
            thisGenre = stg.getGenre();
            thisPrice = stg.getPrice();
            statement.executeUpdate("insert into GameShop (name, genre, price) VALUE " +
                    "('"+thisName+"', '"+thisGenre+"', '"+thisPrice+"')");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: добавьте impot в код основного класса.

Comment: Добавил импорты.

Comment: Какой версии драйвер?

Comment: Версия драйвера 5.1.47

Comment: Обновил коннектор до версии 8.0.12 (аналогичная у mySQL), удалил добавленный вручную jar c драйвером и прописал dependency в мавеновском pom.xml. Результат тот же - тестовй класс работает, основной - кидает ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Для web-приложения, как выяснилось, connector-...jar должен быть еще и добавлен в директорию WEB/WEB-INF/lib. Заработало.